# Get the previous or next item in a map from a for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, stdmap

I'm making a calculator that can accept more than one operator at once (e.g. 5x5x5). I have a map that contains the positions of the operators, and what type they are (x/+-). I also have a for loop           `for (auto const& [key, val] : oper_map)` which I got from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281979/c-loop-through-map) post.

In order to get the left and right numbers, I need to know where the left and right operators are. I've attempted to use `std::prev` and `std::next` with the `key` like this:

```
int loper_pos = -1;
int roper_pos = 0;
double lnum;
double rnum;
char loper;
char roper;

//map defined elsewhere
for (auto const& [key, val] : oper_map)
{
    //loper is left operator while roper is right opeprator

    //tracks the position of the loop
    int map_pos = std::distance(oper_map.begin(), oper_map.find(key)); 

    if (map_pos == 0) loper_pos = -1;
    else
    {
        loper_pos = std::prev(key);
        loper = std::prev(val);
    }
    if (map_pos == oper_map.size()) roper_pos = oper_map.size() + 1;
    else
    {
        roper_pos = std::next(key);
        roper = std::next(val);
    }
```

but I guess it doesn't work since `key` isn't an iterator? I also can't increment/decrement `key` or `val` (or when using the C++11 version in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281979/c-loop-through-map) post), so I guess it doesn't count as an iterator? I don't know iterators confuse me.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215463/c-map-previous-item-of-a-key) post *appears* to be what I want but for whatever reason `lower_bound()` does not work with `oper_map`; no suitable conversion.

Comment: Just change your loop to use an iterator... ?

Comment: when you care about the position don't use a range based loop. The purpose of the range based loop is to hide iterators behind an abstraction, but you want iterators

Comment: I think a `std::vector<std::pair<position, operator>>` would be more suitable. (Actually, there is most likely some even more suitable structure, like a syntax tree.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Huh, well I read somewhere you shouldn't use pairs in a vector when you could use a map, would those values be easier to access?

Comment: " you shouldn't use pairs in a vector when you could use a map" in this generality the statement is just wrong

Comment: @Shidouuu The word "could" is sneaky. In this context, it pretty much means "if you mostly look up specific keys" - that is, if you treat your vector as a map - not "if it is possible". If you're mostly interested in the sequence of values, e.g. finding the previous or next one, a map is less efficient in both time and space (and simplicity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `key` is not an iterator.

```
for (auto const& [key, val] : oper_map)
```

`key` is a `const` reference to the key in the map. If you want iterators, use iterators:

```
for (auto it = oper_map.begin(); it != oper_map.end(); ++it) {
    auto next = std::next(it);
    auto prev = std::prev(it);
}
```

However, consider that `std::map` is not a sequential container. If you are interested in the positions of elements in the container, maybe a `std::vector< std::pair<Key,MappedValue>>` is more handy.

Comment: So for bidirectional iterators, prev/next operators will traverse the entire container to find out the value? Regarding std::map, it is sequential, in that its values are sorted and ordered. So the implementation next/prev for std::map will require red-black tree traversal, using a comparison function from the root node until the last leaf node?

Comment: @bigdata2 I dont remember why i mentioned complexity here. It only matter for the overload that takes `n` to get you the n-th next / previous iterator. `std::next` / `std::prev` never have to traverse the enitre container, only for `std::next( oper_map.begin(), oper_map.size())` or `std::prev(oper_map.end(),oper_map.size())`